# iOS Facebook Request Dialog Not Working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I am following the Facebook iOS tutorial. I'm trying to implement their code:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"Come check out my app.",  @"message",
                           nil];

[facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
              andParams:params
            andDelegate:self];
```

The dialog appears, I add my friends, then I click "Send". At this point nothing appears to happen. My friends (test accounts)  never receive the notification.

This delegate method is called:

```
-(void)dialogDidComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog
{

}
```

Any ideas as to why my friends aren't receiving the notifications?

In essence, what I am trying to do is get people to share this app with their friends. They click on the link and it opens the app in the iTunes app store.  Should I be doing this a different way?

Comment: any updates on this? I am also having a similar issue

Comment: Why are you using "apprequests"? Not sure what it is for messages but for posting on a wall I used facebook dialog:@"stream.publish"

Comment: I'm also having the same issue, please let us know if you solved it. As for @AlexL comment, we are not trying to post on a wall but rather to trigger a notification.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have a canvas url defined for your app.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Also make sure your app delegate is set up.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   APP_ID, @"app_id",
                                   URL_TO_SITE, @"link",
                                   URL_TO_PIC, @"picture",
                                   LINK_TITLE, @"name",
                                   @" ", @"caption",
                                   LINK_DESCRIPTION, @"description",
                                   nil];

[facebook dialog:@"stream.publish"
           andParams:params
         andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Claudia is right. In the app settings you do need to fill-in the 'app on facebook' section and provide a canvas URL.

I guess the point is that if you don't do that there is nothing for facebook to direct an invited user to, so it doesn't display the request.

If your app is purely a mobile app then you could just create a simple webpage for the canvas which directs users to the app store.